# How do I recursively replace part of a string with another given string in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

I need to write bash script that converts a string of only integers "intString" to `:id`. intString always exists after `/`, may never contain any other types (`create_step2` is not a valid intString), and may end at either a second `/` or end of line. intString may be any 1-8 characters. Script needs to be repeated for every line in a given file.

For example:
`/sample/123456/url` should be converted to `/sample/:id/url`
and `/sample_url/9` should be converted to `/sampleurl/:id` however `/sample_url_2/` should remain the same.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you aren't going to show your work thus far and are simply asking if someone can write it for you please do us the courtesy of explaining your project or a justification for why we should help you cheat in your comp-sci class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the long way around the problem to go recursive but then I don't know what problem you are solving.  It seems like a good sed command like

```
sed -E 's/\/[0-9]{1,}/\/:id/g'
```

could do it in one shot, but if you insist on being recursive then it might go something like this ...

```
#!/bin/bash

function restring()
{
    s="$1"
    s="$(echo $s | sed -E 's/\/[0-9]{1,}/\/:id/')"

    if ( echo $s | grep -E '\/[0-9]{1,}' > /dev/null ) ; then
        restring $s
    else
        echo $s
        exit       
    fi

    echo $s
}

restring "$1"
```

now run it

$ ./restring.sh "/foo/123/bar/456/baz/45435/andstuff"

/foo/:id/bar/:id/baz/:id/andstuff